# I am writting a mysql query. Help me out

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a typical situation.
my table has four column. `(id, user, col2, status)`

I want to write a query which gives me the results of col2. But it has a column status which has (0/1). So I want only col2 data which has 0 status + a user's all data (0/1).

```
id user col2 status
1  sam   aa   1
2  sam   bb   0
3  sam   cc   1
4  max   dd   0
5  max   dd   1
6  max    ee  1
7  jam    ff  0
8  jam    gg  1
```

My result should be like. I want sam's all result + other's only 0 status result.

```
id user col2 status

    1  sam   aa   1
    2  sam   bb   0
    3  sam   cc   1
    4  max   dd   0
    7  jam    ff  0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE user = "sam" OR status = 0;
```

?

Answer (score 2):

your where condition would be:
    where (user = 'sam' or status = 0)

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from the_table where user = 'sam' or status = 0 order by id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from yourtable as t
where t.user = "sam"
   or t.status = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE user = 'sam' OR
      status = 0
```

We use `OR` in the `WHERE` clause so that it will be true for all of `sam`'s rows and for all other rows which have `status` as `0`